# Design and Evaluation of Network-Levitated Merge for Hadoop Acceleration

Tags: user-interface, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

i need to develop a project on "Design and Evaluation of Network-Levitated
Merge for HADOOP Acceleration" but i am HADOOP fresher i don't have any idea about HADOOP projects or how to combine the HADOOP functionality with GUI..

please guide me regarding this scenario. .

it would be convenient for me if i get an idea of HADOOP project. .

any simple upload and download project with HADOOP and GUI functionality will do my task. ..

Answer (score 0):

Actually is my M tech project. For this project you need to make changes in HADOOP-0.20.2 and build it again and check the performance of hadoop using terasort. For this Author uses Infiband Network. Author had provided me the code for this project. But it was compiled on older version of linux. which has no update. So i was not able to compile that code. If you have infiband network install OFED in to your system. there is the patch and manual available at mallanox.com. download that manual and follow it.

it it works let me know. otherwise let it go.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. I will try it and let you know. If any problem appear i will ask for a help..